# Polls display according to Role selected in liferay

Tags: portlet, user-roles, liferay-7, usergroups

In liferay, the question selected by Admin in the Polls Display Portlet is displayed to the users. Now what I want to do is, display different question the users with different site Roles. Eg., role1 is assigned to userGroup1 and role2 is assigned to userGroup2 in the same site. Now when I add Polls Display Portlet on a page in Site, question1 has to be selected for userGroup1 and question2 for userGroup2. But now only one question can be selected and if permission is given the question is displayed else error tag "User does not have Permission" is displayed. So how can I achieve the functionality that role wise poll is displayed to the users?

Answer (score 1):

You can put 2 PollS portlet on the page and give view permissions to one for role 1 and then role 2 to the other Polls portlet.

This way the portlet will alternate depending on the rights.

If you getting the do not have permissions message and don't want it. Look into portlet.preferences. You can disable it.